# pass list of values as input parameter to PL/SQL procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

Hi I have a requirement where I get list of values to a input parameter in PL/SQL procedure. The size of the input list varies which is dynamic. How to handle this requirement any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_TEST AS
TYPE X IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
PROCEDURE XYZ(Y IN X);
END PKG_TEST;
/
```

The type can be declared as "TABLE OF" OR "VARRAY(10)";

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE  BODY PKG_TEST AS
PROCEDURE XYZ(Y IN X) AS
BEGIN
  FOR I IN Y.FIRST..Y.LAST
    LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE VALUE OF I IS'||Y(I));
    END LOOP;
  END;
END PKG_TEST;
/

DECLARE   
BEGIN
  PKG_TEST.XYZ('1','2','3','4');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a varchar parameter in sql, each value must be separated by a comma, something like this:
'value1,value2,value3,value4,...,'

So, you can read the values using the function split of sql

I hope that I understood your question

Comment: I didn't understand your reply, I have parameters in procedure as input, but one of teh input needed to be a list.

Comment: why dont you write some of your code? The statement of your procedure and your list, maybe I'll understand